# How to setup nginx as reverse proxy with LetsEncrypt SSL encryption using Docker

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am trying to setup SSL for my homepage (`www.myhomepage.com`) using LetsEncrypt on a nginx reverse-proxy. I have an additional host without SSL running for testing proxying to multiple hosts (`www.myotherhomepagewithoutssl.com`).

The reverse-proxy and two hosts are running in three separate docker containers.

I got both hosts to work without SSL, but the encrypted one does not work, when trying to use SSL. The LetsEncrypt certificates appear to be setup/obtained correctly and are persisted in a docker volume.

I am trying to follow and adapt this tutorial to setup the LetsEncrypt SSL encryption:
http://tom.busby.ninja/letsecnrypt-nginx-reverse-proxy-no-downtime/

When trying to connect to the SSL encrypted host under `www.myhomepage.com` using Firefox I get this error:

> Unable to connect

The other non-encrypted host under `www.myotherhomepagewithoutssl.com` works. And as I stated above, when I have `www.myhomepage.com` setup without SSL (in the same way as `www.myotherhomepagewithoutssl.com`), it is also reachable.

My complete setup is listed below and consists of:
* `reverse_proxy_testing.sh`: Bash script to clean-up, build and start the containers.
* `compose_reverse_proxy.yaml`: Docker-Compose file.
* `reverse_proxy.docker`: Dockerfile for setting up the reverse-proxy with nginx.
* `nginx.conf`: nginx config-file for the reverse-proxy.

I suspect that my error is located somewhere inside `nginx.conf`, but I cannot find it.

Any help is much appreciated!

**nginx.conf**:

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    sendfile on;

    server {
        deny all;
    }

    upstream myhomepage {
        server myhomepage_blog:80;
    }

    upstream docker-apache {
        server apache:80;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name www.myhomepage.com myhomepage.com;
        return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }


    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443;

        server_name www.myhomepage.com myhomepage.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myhomepage.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myhomepage.com/privkey.pem;

        location /.well-known {
            root /var/www/ssl-proof/myhomepage.com/;
        }


        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://myhomepage;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_read_timeout 900s;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.myotherhomepagewithoutssl.com myotherhomepagewithoutssl.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://docker-apache;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }

}
```

**reverse_proxy.docker**:

```
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/ssl-proof/myhomepage.com/.well-known

RUN apk update && apk add certbot
```

**compose_reverse_proxy.yaml**:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
    reverseproxy:
        image: reverseproxy
        ports:
            - 80:80
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - proxy_letsencrypt_ssl_proof:/var/www/ssl-proof
            - proxy_letsencrypte_certificates:/etc/letsencrypt

    apache:
        depends_on:
            - reverseproxy
        image: httpd:alpine
        restart: always

    myhomepage_blog:
        image: wordpress
        links:
            - myhomepage_db:mysql
        environment:
            - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=somepassword
            - VIRTUAL_HOST=myhomepage.com
        volumes:
            - myhomepage_code:/code
            - myhomepage_html:/var/www/html
        restart: always

    myhomepage_db:
        image: mariadb
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=somepassword
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
        volumes:
            - myhomepage_dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always

volumes:
    myhomepage_dbdata:
    myhomepage_code:
    myhomepage_html:
    proxy_letsencrypt_ssl_proof:
    proxy_letsencrypte_certificates:
```

**reverse_proxy_testing.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker rm testreverseproxy_apache_1 testreverseproxy_myhomepage_blog_1 testreverseproxy_myhomepage_db_1 testreverseproxy_reverseproxy_1
docker build -t reverseproxy -f reverse_proxy.docker .
docker-compose -f  reverse_proxy_compose.yml up
```

Comment: You need to pass port 443 into 'reverseproxy', and you need to specify 'ssl' on both (or all) listen directives for the ssl port (443).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 That did the trick - thanks! I you want to formulate your comment as an answer, I would gladly accept it.